# How to embed an youtube video in shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, youtube, embed, shinydashboard

I'm trying to embed a youtube video to my dashboard and it seems to be a straightforward thing, but it doesn't work for me. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Here's my code for a test dashboard:

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
   fluidRow(
     column(3, 
            box(
              width = NULL, 
              title = "YT Video Here", 
              HTML('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
            )),
     column(9,
            box(
              width = NULL, 
              title = "Other Content"))
   )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What do you meant by `doesn't work`? - (showing error, video not running, warning message etc.)  The code is working fine for me.  I changed to different videos as well, all of them are running fine.  Can you pls check the `packageVersion`

Comment: Huh! That is strange! Good to know that the code works. I just get an empty box with no content and no error message. Will update the package and check again. Thanks!

Comment: @SreejaS, did you figure it out. IT doesnt seems to be working for me. I too see just a box there instead of a video

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam Sorry for the late response. Mine turned out to be a super silly problem actually. It only showed a box when it showed up on the R console, but when I opened it in the browser, it showed up fine. Hope that helps!

Comment: @SreejaS, Apparently. that was exactly the case with me. Once I published it to shiny, it worked fine. I had to republish it multiple times to adjust the box and the video inside it which was super inconvenient but it worked. Although, I eventually moved to Dash as it gave me more flexibility.